# Which of the following sentences are correct?

Tags: conditional-constructions, possessives, perfect-constructions

> (A) Without correct mistakes, we could not improve.
>   (B) Without having our mistakes corrected, we can not improve.

Also:

> (C) Without had wings, birds could not fly.
>   (D) Without wings, birds could not fly.

Comment: I like (B) and (D). I also think you might like [ell.se].

Comment: A, B and D are correct. But only B and D are fine to me. *Without* is a preposition here and you could change C this way to make it correct too: *Without having wings, birds could not fly.*"

Answer (score 1):

B and D are grammatically correct.

A is grammatically correct, but **correct mistakes** sounds self-contradictory in the same way Noam Chomsky's famous sentence is:  "Colorless green ideas sleep furiously".  I can imagine a case where some mistake could be the "correct mistake" for some special situation, but usually "correct" and "mistake" don't go together logically.

C is ungrammatical because **had** can't be used in that construction:  it's past tense, and the sentence is in the abstract present, for which **having** would work (but the construction in D would be more often heard).

Comment: As a footnote: Sentence A would be fine if _correct_ was changed to _corrected_.